# In windows,How to start appium server without mentioning any specific ports and utilize available free ports?

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Am using Java code to start Appium server using Command Line Agruments mentioning a specific port in it.Am looking currently how to start the appium server with using available ports in windows machine.

Comment: have you installed using node.js command prompt or you have install appium server

Comment: Using node.js By taking reference from Method 2 mentioned in  http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the appium using node js then you can start using following command

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723
```

If you have download the .exe file then you have to open the executable file and it will show you like this..

[image]

then you have to click the start appium server button and if the server start sucessfully then it will look like this..

[image]

Comment: Is there a  way to open appium without mentioning Ports ?

Comment: Actually port is required so the system can transfer the data to device hence, you have issued with the ports why are you asking you can use whatever port you want

Comment: Am keeping my framework in CI but when am trying to start appium server am getting an connection refused error because port was not free hence i need to change the port daily

Comment: You have more than 65000 of ports available in you computer you can use anything..

Comment: But i have to keep changing everytime manually is there way to do using Java or some other it would be great

Comment: Can't help you then because ports are required to transfer data otherwise not able to contact with each other

Answer (score 0):

To start appium service without providing any port, you can  use **AppiumDriverLocalService** class and **AppiumServiceBuilder**. We will use  method 'usingAnyFreePort()' which Configures the appium server to start on any available port. Node.js should be installed on system to achieve it.

We need to provide path of Appium node.exe file path and appium.js file path as below :

```
    String Appium_Node_Path="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe";

                //Appium.js file can be available on one of these 2 path
    String Appium_JS_Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\build\lib/appium.js";

             OR          

    String Appium_JS_Path="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js";
     AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService";

appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort().usingDriverExecutable(new File(Appium_Node_Path)).withAppiumJS(new File(Appium_JS_Path)));
    appiumService.start();
```

Comment: How to driver Intialize with the Apprium URL if we use 'usingAnyFreePort()' ?

Comment: get url string like 'String appiumServiceUrl = appiumService.getUrl().toString();' and utilize it as URL 'driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), capabilities);'